# Есть ли библиотеки JavaScript для решения дифференциальных уравнений?

Tags: javascript

У меня сейчас стоит задача с ВУЗ`а - написать сайт-калькулятор, на котором можно решать дифференциальные уравнения. Обыскал уже всё, никак ничего подходящего не могу найти. Есть ли библиотеки JavaScript для решения этих дифференциальных уравнений?

Comment: например `math.js`: https://mathjs.org/index.html

Comment: Может для начала поработаете над проблемой? Какие диф уравнения вы собираетесь решать. Если обыкновенные то задача сводится к решению полинома?  Если прочие то какие? Решения в каком виде вам сказали предоставить. ....

Comment: @AzizUmarov, мне нужно чтобы код мог выводить ответ на уравнение (даже самое простое, главное чтобы хоть какие-то можно было решить). Ввод - вывод